# A task was canceled - what does this mean?

Tags: asynchronous, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I'm using the Azure Search .Net SDK.

I'm calling a synchronous (NOT ASYNC) function like this:

```
var searchResults = searchIndexClient.Documents.Search<T>(searchText, searchParameters);
```

It usually works. I'm not using any async functions, but somehow the error I just got looks like an async error:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.

CancellationToken: IsCanceleationRequested=false

Task: Id = 556, Status = Canceled, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"

StackTrace:
```

> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Search.DocumentsOperations.<DoContinueSearchWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__15`3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Search.DocumentsOperationsExtensions.<SearchAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.Azure.Search.DocumentsOperationsExtensions.Search[T](IDocumentsOperations operations, String searchText, SearchParameters searchParameters, SearchRequestOptions searchRequestOptions)
>      at MyApp.AzureSearch.AzureSearchService.PerformSearch[T](String searchText, SearchParameters searchParameters) in c:\Projects\MyAppServer\src\MyApp.AzureSearch\AzureSearchService.cs:line 359
>      at MyApp.AzureSearch.AzureSearchService.Search[T](String searchText, List`1 searchFields, SearchMode searchMode, List`1 select, Nullable`1 skip, Nullable`1 top, String filter, Boolean includeTotalResultCount, List`1 orderBy) in c:\Projects\MyAppServer\src\MyApp.AzureSearch\AzureSearchService.cs:line 262
>      at MyApp.AzureSearch.AzureSearchService.SearchEmails(Guid userId, String origin, String searchText, Nullable`1 skip, Nullable`1 top, Boolean includeTotalResultCount, Boolean includeHtmlBody, Boolean orderByProcessedAscending, String interactionStatus) in c:\Projects\MyAppServer\src\MyApp.AzureSearch\AzureSearchService.cs:line 167
>      at MyApp.Domain.MyAppMessages.Command.MyAppMessagesAllNoticedUpdater.Handle(VisitorSession userSession, NoticeAllMyAppMessages processCommand) in c:\Projects\MyAppServer\src\MyApp.Domain\MyAppMessages\Command\MyAppMessagesAllNoticedUpdater.cs:line 30

Comment: i had same issue and drafted my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73424728/6271132)

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, the client timeout expired before the search has completed. Are you seeing this error when you submit a particularly complex query? If needed, you can look at the search performance in your service using [search traffic analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/analyzing-your-azure-search-traffic/).

The reason you're seeing an "asynchronous" exception is that the synchronous version of the API is just a wrapper over asynchronous primitives.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was just wrapping an async function. It wasn't a complex query at all, and very little data in the query as well. I didn't expect the .net SDK to throw an error unless something was misconfigured in the query. Is there a list of all possible errors that can be thrown by the .net sdk that I should handle?

Comment: The main exceptions that can be thrown are: `CloudException`, `IndexBatchException` (for indexing only), `ValidationException`, and of course `OperationCanceledException` (or its subclass `TaskCanceledException` you're dealing with here). But since C# is not a checked exception language, you might see other exceptions as well (such as ArgumentException).

Answer (score 0):

Pass CancellationToken=null and make the code as async methods.