# HttpClient - A task was cancelled exception

Tags: c#, httpclient

I usually make a get request from my console application to the api application. Sometimes I encounter the error "A task was canceled" in production environment. But somehow I cannot produce the same error in the development environment.

Error:

```
    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at WebApiClient.HttpClientExtensions.HttpClientExtension.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<ExecuteGetAsync>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

The code I made a request and encountered the error:

```
try
{
    var result = await WebApiClient.BuildHttpClient(new Uri("www.domain.com/")).ExecuteGetAsync<string>("requestUrl");

    return result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

My client code:

```
public class WebApiClient
{
    public static HttpClient BuildHttpClient(Uri baseAddress)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        return client;
    }
}

public static partial class HttpClientExtension
{
    public static Task<TResult> ExecuteGetAsync<TResult>(this HttpClient httpClient, string requestUri)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var response = httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;
            httpClient.Dispose();

            try
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return response.Content
                    .ReadAsStringAsync()
                    .ContinueWith(jsonTask =>
                    {
                        var json = jsonTask.Result;
                        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(json);
                    });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                IDictionary data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (var httpResponseHeader in response.Headers)
                {
                    data.Add(httpResponseHeader.Key, httpResponseHeader.Value.First());
                }

                throw new HttpRequestFailedException(response.StatusCode.ToString(), data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it could be that the request timed out in production

Comment: make all calls async, don't mix await and .Result

Comment: @KhanhTO The default timeout time is 100000 milliseconds. I did not play with the timeout time. But I get an exception approximately 263 seconds after I send a request.

Comment: @Crowcoder 
var response = httpClient.GetAsync (requestUri) .Result;

I use async / await everywhere except this code. Should I change the .result in this code?

Comment: 263 seconds is more than 100000 milliseconds. It should time out.

Comment: everywhere you run an async method, you should await it, including `response.Content
                    .ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: You can use `Task.Run(async () => { var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);`

Comment: @Genusatplay it is a waste of threadpool resources to Task Run an async method

Comment: @Crowcoder I did not understand exactly how to do it. I thought you wanted me to do as Genusatplay said.

Comment: @Crowcoder why? if you want deserialize in task

Comment: @KhanhTo Yes, I realize it's big. But I guess it wouldn't have made an error after such a long time if it had timeout. I would expect to get an exception after 101 seconds or something.

Comment: @Genusatplay because you are forcing a thread from the pool to run an async method that would not normally even tie up a thread at all

Comment: @Crowcoder I removed .Result and Task.Run(). I used async/await

`public static async Task<TResult> ExecuteGetAsync<TResult>(this HttpClient httpClient, string requestUri)`

`var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);`

`return await response.Content`

Comment: How often does the api call happen? it might be interesting  https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: @Genusatplay I've seen this, but I no longer have the possibility to use static clients. I am not making enough requests to cause this problem anyway. Even so, I think I will get socket exception.

Comment: Check the Event Viewer in server for errors.Do you know if real error is occuring in client or server? Right now you do not know if the exception is occuring.  There is 5 possibilities 1) In client before request is sent  2) While request is being transmitted to server 3) In Server while processing is occurring 4) When response is being sent from server to client 5) While client is parsing the response.  You may want to use a sniffer to determine which of the 5 is actually occurring.  HTTP uses TCP as transport layer so make sure you check for a TCP [FIN] which indicates TCP closed connection.

Comment: **don't** dispose the httpclient. That not how httpclient works

Answer (score 3):

I was getting same issue recently but when i was trying to making a simple post call with `json` payload.

Tried passing `CancellationToken` as null, increased `timeout` and all different ways of making a post call using `httpclient` with and without `async await` but none worked for us.

As a troubleshooting step, used `postman` and surprisingly it was working all fine with `postman`, later had compared the request `packets` which i was sending to the server with postman request `packets` using `wireshark` tool and found to be like the request was expecting `100 continue` from server which was weird though the request has got nothing more data to send. Suspect was related to `content-length` in the request being passed as it was expecting `100 continue` which we don't have control to.

Using `Restsharp` `nuget` library solved the issue for us, though it uses `httpclient` under the hood.